# Why can I input an argument on a scale?

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js

I'm doing a simple histogram:

```
var width = 500,
  height = 500,
  padding = 50;
d3.csv('mydata.csv', function(data) {
  var map = data.map(function(i) {
    return parseInt(i.age)
  })
  var histogram = d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(7)(map)
  console.log(histogram)

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(histogram.map(function(i) {
      return i.length;
    }))])
    .range([0, height])

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(map)])
    .range([0, width]);

  var canvas = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height + padding);

  var bars = canvas.selectAll(".bar").data(histogram)
    .enter().append('g').attr('class', 'bar')
  bars.append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return x(d.x);
    })
    .attr('y', 0)
    .attr('width', function(d) {
      return x(d.dx);
    })
    .attr('height', function(d) {
      return y(d.y)
    })
    .attr('fill', 'purple')

})
```

I'm using [Youtube to learn D3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0CZ7-f9wXiM&list=PL6il2r9i3BqH9PmbOf5wA5E1wOG3FT22p&index=18)

The `scale` variable `x` and `y` aren't functions, but even if they were functions they don't have parameters.

But In the `bars.append('rect')`, `return x(d.x)`,  `return x(d.dx)` and `return y(d.y)` are acting like functions that also have parameters...

Can someone explain to me how is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that...

> The scale variable x and y aren't functions.

Well, that's incorrect. D3 scales (in any version) are functions. In you case, you have a D3 v3 scale.

To show you that this is a scale, and what argument it takes, let's see D3 v3 [source code](https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js). It will take us through a labyrinth of functions returning functions.

This is the `d3.scale.linear()` function:

```
d3.scale.linear = function() {
    return d3_scale_linear([0, 1], [0, 1], d3_interpolate, false);
};
```

As you can see, it returns a function, `d3_scale_linear`. That function takes 4 arguments, the first two are the default range and domain. Obviously, you can change both the range and the domain later, as you did.

If you look at `d3_scale_linear`, you'll see that it returns this function:

```
function rescale() {
    var linear = Math.min(domain.length, range.length) > 2 ? d3_scale_polylinear : d3_scale_bilinear,
        uninterpolate = clamp ? d3_uninterpolateClamp : d3_uninterpolateNumber;
    output = linear(domain, range, uninterpolate, interpolate);
    input = linear(range, domain, uninterpolate, d3_interpolate);
    return scale;
}
```

Which by its turn returns this function:

```
function scale(x) {
    return output(x);
}
```

And that `x` is the argument that you pass to the scale when you use it, like `x(d.x)` in your example. The passed argument is `d.x`.

Just for completeness, the `output` function depends on either `d3_scale_polylinear` or `d3_scale_bilinear`, which are the functions that perform the real job:

```
function d3_scale_bilinear(domain, range, uninterpolate, interpolate) {
    var u = uninterpolate(domain[0], domain[1]),
        i = interpolate(range[0], range[1]);
    return function(x) {
        return i(u(x));
    };
}

function d3_scale_polylinear(domain, range, uninterpolate, interpolate) {
    var u = [],
        i = [],
        j = 0,
        k = Math.min(domain.length, range.length) - 1;
    if (domain[k] < domain[0]) {
        domain = domain.slice().reverse();
        range = range.slice().reverse();
    }
    while (++j <= k) {
        u.push(uninterpolate(domain[j - 1], domain[j]));
        i.push(interpolate(range[j - 1], range[j]));
    }
    return function(x) {
        var j = d3.bisect(domain, x, 1, k) - 1;
        return i[j](u[j](x));
    };
}
```

Comment: Misread the docs and had a brain shortcut, my answer was all wrong. Sorry. Deleting.

Comment: thank you! function have so many functions. At the end of function, It can have function that require arugment that i have to pass..